# Slick carousel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to use slick carousel to slide the year of a calendar but I can't make it work.

Here's what I want to make slide:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div class='slick'><a style='color: #cccccc;' onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div class='slick'><a style='color: #cccccc;' onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
```

And when I use this part on my code, this don't work...

```js
$('.slick').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 5,
  responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 768,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '40px',
    slidesToShow: 3
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '40px',
    slidesToShow: 1
  }
}
  ]
});
```

I wanted that when I click on `<` or `>` make the month to slide, but I can't.

Thank u very much.

Here I have the PHP code where is the library:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
 
    <script src="js/semanal.js"></script>
 <script src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <center>
<table id="calendar">
<p>
 <caption></caption>
 <thead>
 
  <tr>
   <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <script>mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+1);</script>
 
 </tbody>
</table>
 </center>
</body>
<script src="js/semanal.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included the slick carousel library somewhere on the page?

Comment: should it be: $('.slick').slick...

Comment: Yep, I edited it...@WebCode.ie

Comment: @JohnKane I tryed but when I use that part of the code make all my calendar going empty..It's something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you are appending you html with javascript, it may be that when slick loads, the content is not available yet, try putting `$('.slick').slick()` inside a `setTimeOut()` function. Also you have this line twice `<script src="js/semanal.js"></script>` and the second time it should be before the closing body tag, so fix that and also consider moving the rest of the scripts there (before the closing body tag).

EDIT

You need to put all your slides inside a single .slick element so you need to do something like this. Look at the changes i made to your markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <table id="calendar">
            <caption>
                <div class="slick"></div> 
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>
    <script src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/semanal.js"></script>
    <script>mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+1);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I moved this to different lines for readability, look that i removed the slick classes and made it find slick class and not caption tag

```
document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByClass("slick")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div>"+
"<div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div>"+
"<div><a style='color: #cccccc;' onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div>"+
"<div><a style='color: #cccccc;' onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>"+
"<div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div class='slick'>"+meses[month-2]+"</div>"+
"<div>"+meses[month]+"</div>"
```

Comment: I edited the part when I use the slick, see that if u can...but it still not working...I made the changes that u said but doesn't work...Thank u for ur help

Comment: Sorry, i didn't looked to much in the line that appends the slider, that's not how you have to use slick, i recommend you to check the documentation. You need to put a single <div class="slick"></div> and inside of it the divs with the slides, here you are creating 5 empty sliders, i will edit my answer to show you an example

Comment: It doesn't work when I change the caption tag from "caption" to "slick", the whole caption appear empty...